# access java base class's static member in scala

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, static, scala-java-interop

Ｉhave some codes written in Java. And for new classes I plan to write in Scala. I have a problem regarding accessing the protected static member of the base class. Here is the sample code:

*Java code:*

```
class Base{
    protected static int count = 20;
}
```

*scala code:*

```
class Derived extends Base{
    println(count);
}
```

Any suggestion on this? How could I solve this without modifying the existing base class

Comment: If there are no access modifiers on the base class they have to be in the same package, else this won't work.

Comment: sorry, we do have public modifier on the base class, but still doesn't work.

Comment: How about saying what the problem is? Any error message?

Comment: seems when we place the two classes in different packages, we will get compile error: variable a in object B cannot be accessed in object com.fcy.sss.B Access to protected variable a not  permitted because enclosing class class D is not a subclass of object B in package sss where target is  defined   These are the files:
B.java file:
package com.fcy.sss;

public class B {
    protected static int a = 30;

}

D.scala file:
import com.fcy.sss.B
class D extends B{
    println(B.a);
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible in Scala. Since Scala has no notation of `static` you can't access `protected static` members of a parent class. This is a [known limitation](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4#4n1381).

The work-around is to do something like this:

```
// Java
public class BaseStatic extends Base {
  protected int getCount() { return Base.count; }
  protected void setCount(int c) { Base.count = c; }
}
```

Now you can inherit from this new class instead and access the static member through the getter/setter methods:

```
// Scala
class Derived extends BaseStatic {
  println(getCount());
}
```

It's ugly—but if you really want to use `protected static` members then that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: Thanks, I have to do it this way for now

Comment: Is that true for protected methods? In particular protected constructors?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - There are similar issues with accessing protected members of an ancestor's companion object, but other than that I think you'll be OK for non-static methods/constructors.

Comment: @DaoWen I'm asking because right now I have problems extending guava's [FinalizablePhantomReference](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/FinalizablePhantomReference.java?r=69#32) and thinking is this desired behaviour or should I report it