# Instantiate nested class in Scala when extending Java class

Tags: java, scala

I have abstract java class which contains nested class declared as `protected static`:

```
public abstract class AbstractJavaClass {
  // contains nested class
  protected static class InnerClass {
  ...
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to instantiate it in Scala class extending AbstractJavaClass like I do in java (i.e. just referring name inside method new InnerClass):

```
class ScalaClass extends AbstractJavaClass {
   def method = new InnerClass()
}
```

I get error: *type InnerClass is not a member of ScalaClass*. What am I doing wrong? The same in java works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled here: [access java base class's static member in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034017/access-java-base-classs-static-member-in-scala)

It says

```
This isn't possible in Scala. Since Scala has no notation of static you can't
access protected static members of a parent class. This is a known limitation.
```

Though I couldn't resolve initial issue (when class is `protected static`), when I changed it to `public static` in definition of `AbstractJavaClass` I could use it this way:

```
class ScalaClass extends AbstractJavaClass {
  import AbstractJavaClass.InnerClass

  def method = new InnerClass
}
```

Using `new InnerClass` without import gives the same error.